# Making label with dashed or dotted text decoration in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

is anybody know how to underline label in Xamarin.Forms (Android/iOS) using dashed or dotted line. In regular XAML I can use only solid line to do this.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately , Xamarin.Forms doesn't support  dashed or dotted underline until now . In iOS , you could set double underline by using Custom Renderer. But dashed or dotted is still unavailable both in Android and iOS . The only way is to re-draw the label , which will be very complex .

Comment: I've expected this unfortunately, cuz even uncle Google doesn't know anything about it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes, please, I think I've got an answer for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately , Xamarin.Forms doesn't support dashed or dotted underline until now . In iOS , you could set double underline by using Custom Renderer.

```
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

using App4;
using App4.iOS;
using CoreAnimation;
using CoreGraphics;

[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(Label),typeof(MyLabelRenderer))]
namespace App4.iOS
{
    public class MyLabelRenderer:LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);


            if (Control != null)
            {
                var content = Control.Text;

                UIStringAttributes attributes = new UIStringAttributes() { UnderlineStyle = NSUnderlineStyle.double, UnderlineColor = UIColor.Red, BaselineOffset = 0, };

                NSMutableAttributedString str = new NSMutableAttributedString(content, attributes);

                Control.AttributedText = str;
            }


        }
    }
}
```

And you could also use the plugin **[HtmlLabelPlugin](https://github.com/matteobortolazzo/HtmlLabelPlugin)** from nuget to display HTML content into a label. But in iOS , some tags seem unavailable .

I will post it as a Feature Request and reply you if has any update as soon as possible .